# rx android vs mosby pattern load data recyclerview

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview, rx-android

I am working on an Android app. The code I attach is creating a recyclerview. The very first thing we do is to create an asynctask that would fetch data on an SQLite database and load it into the adapter->recylcerview. While the background task is working, a progressdialog is shown to the user.

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private RecyclerView recycler;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefresh;
    private progressDialog progressDialog;

     // ... some code here

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // ... some code here


    createRecyclerView();
    loadRecyclerView();


    // ... some code here

    }


    private void loadRecyclerView()
    {
        new LoadingBackgroundTask().execute();
    }



    private void createRecyclerView()
{

    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycle_view_home);
    recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager lManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(lManager);

    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter();

    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    recycler.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

}

private class LoadingBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<items>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(HomeActivity.this, getString(R.string.dialog_load_list),getString(R.string.dialog_please_wait), false, false);

    }

    @Override
    protected List doInBackground(Void... params) {

        List<items> lists;
        //Data Source Class ( SQLite)
        ListDS listDS = new ListDS(getApplicationContext());
        list = listDS.getList();

        return list;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        //it inserts de list on recyclerview performing animation
        adapter.animate(result);

        progressDialog.dissmiss();
        swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
        recycler.scrollToPosition(0);
    }

}

}
```

So far, so good. However, as you probably know this code has some well-known issues; for example if I rotate the screen while asynctask is doing its magic, it will crash the app.

I've tried an alternative I've seen Googling, *rxandroid*.

(Sorry if I typed something wrong, I am doing it by memory)

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
 private Subscriber suscriptor;
private progressDialog progressDialog;

 //some code ....

  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    suscriptor = new Subscriber() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.d("SUSCRIPTOR","ON COMPLETE");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.d("SUSCRIPTOR","ON ERROR");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Object o) {
            adapter.animate((List<items>)o);

        }
    };


    Observable.create(
            new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<items>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Subscriber<? super List<items>> sub) {
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(HomeActivity.this,  getString(R.string.dialog_load_list),getString(R.string.dialog_please_wait), false, false);
                    List<items> lists;
                    //Data Source Class ( SQLite)
                    ListDS listDS = new ListDS(getApplicationContext());
                    list = listDS.getList();

                    sub.onNext(list);
                    sub.onCompleted();

                }

                @Override
                protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
                    super.finalize();
                    Log.d("OBSERAVBLE","FINALIZED");
                }
            })
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
           .cache()
    .subscribe(suscriptor);

    }


@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    if(suscriptor!=null)
    {
        if(!suscriptor.isUnsubscribed())
        {
            suscriptor.unsubscribe();
        }
    }

    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

Now the app is not crashing anymore when I rotate the screen. However, the observable keeps working on the background until it finishes but as I unsubscribe to avoid crashing, I don't receive the results properly. Moreover, progressbar disappears even though the observable keeps working as I mentioned.

Looking for a solution, I found there is a pattern called "Ted Mosby" which seems to solve my problem. Although it looks promising, I think is too much coding for something I felt it is not worth it and that rxandroid may have a workaround.

So, my question is how can I get what I want without getting immersed in an architectural coding mess too big for my purpose? Could you give an example if you guys have solved this? Do you think I am wrong and I should implement TedMosby pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mosby is a **M**odel-**V**iew-**P**resenter (MVP) library. So the pattern you named "ted mosby pattern" is actually MVP.

But you didn't have understood what MVP is all about. It's not about retaining async running taks, even thought this could be achieved with Mosby. MVP is about separation of concerns. View is just displaying UI elements, Presenter is controlling the View, i.e. the presenter tells the view: now display the progress diaolog, now hide the progress dialog, etc. In other words, the presenter controls the state of the view. The Model could be an async task or a RxJava Observable. The Presenter than gets the result back and tell the view to display it. You code is decoupled into 3 layers  Model (also called business logic) and Presenter and View. The advantage is that you can change the view (i.e. replace progress dialog with an progressbar widget) without touching any code that loads data (Presenter and business logic). Additionally with MVP your code becomes testable.

So what you should compare is: Should I use `AsyncTask` or `RxJava` for loading data. With Mosby you would execute your http request in the presenter. While orientation changes are done the presenter doesn't get destroyed (and hence the background task doesn't get canceled).

However, MVP is not the solution for everything. If you have to ensure that a single http call is executed correctly (i.e. sign up for a community) you should think about using an android service.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is whatever you do in activity like your `AsycTask` and `RecyclerView`, put it inside a fragment and, `setRetainInstance(true)` in `onCreateView()` method of fragment and load that fragment in your activity.

`setRetainInstance(true)` won't let your fragment instance destroy when screen is rotated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Observable` should handle himself the fact on unsubscription. There are two mechanism for this:

- check `subscriber.isUnsubscribed`. You can do it between or after "heavy" steps
- add unsubscription callback. You can use it to stop long running operations, release resources etc

Take a look at this code:

```
Observable.create(
        new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<items>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super List<items>> sub) {
                sub.add(Subscriptions.create(new Action0() {
                    @Override
                    public void call() {
                        cancelLongRunningOperationIfItStillRunning();
                    }
                }));
                if (!sub.isUnsubscribed()) {
                    //start long running operation here
               }
            }
        })
        .doOnSubscribe(new Action0() {
            @Override
            public void call() {
            }
        })
```

You shouldn't reference to your activity/context/progress dialog etc inside `Observable`. Instead use `doOnSubscribe` if you want to do some side effects.